# SQL Server : find dates between two separate row entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull a list of `AccountNumbers` that have 2 specific charges (by code) that are at least 2 days apart. These are the columns of my table:

- AccountNumber
- ServiceDate
- Code

Example: if there is `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33967` on `ServiceDate 12/11/2018` and an `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33968` on `ServiceDate 12/15/2018`, the `AccountNumber` will be output to the results window because these two instances show up on DIFFERENT `ServiceDate`s and are at least 2 days apart.

Example 2: if there is an `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33967` on `ServiceDate` 12/11/2018 and an `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33968` on `ServiceDate` 12/11/2018, the `AccountNumber` will NOT be output to the results window because these two instances show up on the same `ServiceDate`.

Example 3: if there is an `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33967` on `ServiceDate` 12/11/2018 and an `AccountNumber` for `Code = 33968` on ServiceDate `12/12/2018`, the `AccountNumber` will NOT be output to the results window because there are no dates between the two `ServiceDate`'s. However if it were 12/11 and 12/13 it would be acceptable because there is a day in-between.

I am only concerned about Code 33967 and 33968, all other codes should not be considered. Right now, I am able to pull all Accounts with both these codes on file but cannot figure out how to go further. Any ideas?

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, ServiceDate 
FROM dbo.table
WHERE Code = '33968'

INTERSECT

SELECT AccountNumber, ServiceDate 
FROM dbo.table
WHERE Code = '33967'
```

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Example 2 doesn't make any sense.   It sounds like you're saying 12/11/2018 is the same date as 12/15/2018, which it clearly isn't.

Comment: @TabAlleman my bad, copy/pasted from example1. It is fixed now!

Comment: you basically need-ed a way to account for min(ServiceDate) . I have given you an example below that does this. Try it out and let us know if it meets your desired output answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go with some sample data. Feel free to add some more rows and test it up

```
      create table #Temp_table
    (
    AccountNumber int null
    , ServiceDate date null
    ,Code int null
    )
    insert into #Temp_table values
    (1,'12/11/2018',33967)
    ,(2,'12/15/2018',33968)
    ,(3,'12/11/2018',33967)
    ,(4,'12/12/2018',33968)
,(5,'12/17/2018',33968)
,(6,'12/16/2018',33967)


    ;with CTE_MinDate as (
    select --Code ,
    MinServiceDate = min(Servicedate)
    from #Temp_table 
    --group by Code
    )
    --select * from CTE_MinDate

    select *
    from (
    select *
    ,Days_Diff = datediff(day,MinServiceDate, Servicedate)
    from (
    select a.*
    ,MinServiceDate = (select MinServiceDate from CTE_MinDate)
    from #Temp_table a
    where a.Code in ( 33967,33968)
    ) a
    ) b where Days_Diff >= 2
```

Comment: I edited my code to reflect all. lmk if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey @junketsu, this was a huge help and solved my problem! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.AccountNumber
FROM dbo.table t
WHERE t.Code = '33968' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.table t2
              WHERE t2.AccountNumber = t.AccountNumber AND
                    t2.Code = '33967' AND
                    t2.ServiceDate <> t.ServiceDate
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the Account Number you want then how about:

```
SELECT AccountNumber
FROM dbo.[Table]
GROUP BY AccountNumber
HAVING COUNT(CASE CODE WHEN 33968 THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE CODE WHEN 33967 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```